# Robust way to keep records of software releases?

Tags: version-control, tools, release

We release a number of small plug-ins that go along with our software.  Each plug-in allows our software to talk to a single manufactuer's hardware.  I would like to devise a system for keeping track of plug-in releases.

### Example info that should be stored:

- Hardware manufacturer name
- 32-bit? 64-bit? both?
- What modes of operation does the hardware support?
- What versions of the manufacturer's driver have been tested with the plugin?

### Desirable properties of the system:

- Able to synchronize with version control software
- Stores data in human-readable text file (also good for differ tool)
- Free visual, spreadsheet-like editor available
- Able to do simple analysis like "What is the oldest plug-in?"

I've got to imagine that someone else has tackled this problem already.  Right now my best guess is XML/JSON with a visual editor, but I have been disappointed in the editors I've tried so far.  I'd like to get input from some more experienced developers.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do this with appropriate uses of repositories, branching and tagging in the VCS of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Continuous integration is probably something you'd find useful for this task.

I'd recommend you have a look at [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) (or [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)<sup>1</sup>).

Essentially it's a build robot, and you can arbitrarily add scripts and activities to be run as part of the build process. For example, monitor the SCM repository for changes and trigger a build, run unit tests, log information about the build, etc. etc.

If you send log entries to a database (e.g. SQlite) you'll be able to do any queries you like.

<sup>1. the [Hudson/Jenkins split.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29#The_Hudson_Jenkins_Split)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you *were* working with Debian packages, you could just do ls/find on your pool directory.